# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at splitting string

Tags: android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

In my Android app I have a string which value is always from type `yo_2014_rojo`.
I need to split the string in three parts: `part1 ="yo"` `part2="2014"` and `part3="rojo"`.

I am trying to do it as follows:

```
String s[] = dato_seleccionado.split("_");
String s1 = s[0];
String s2 = s[1];
String s3 = s[2];
```

but the app crashes with an exception: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You'll need to put a breakpoint, it seems `dato_seleccionado` is not in the form you expect when it crashes, otherwise that would work just fine.

Comment: @Zach If it was null, OP would get a NPE. It's definitely not null.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, I have inserted a log to check the value of dato_seleccionado and it is currently 12_Diciembre_2014...the exception says length=1,index=1

Comment: Time for me to go home haha, comment removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
String str = "yo_2014_rojo";
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(str , "_");
String part1 = token.nextToken(); //yo
String part2 = token.nextToken(); //2014
String part3 = token.nextToken(); //rojo
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

```
String[] spliced = dato_seleccionado.split("_");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spliced)); // check if you have the correct output

String s1 = spliced[0];
String s2 = spliced[1];
String s3 = spliced[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

`stringname.split()` takes Perl regex as an argument.

Try escaping the underscore, like this:

```
String[] spliced = dato_seleccionado.split("\\_");
```